# Remove MokManager Password

Tags: linux, boot

When my PC boot, MokManager asks for password. I must forget it - or somebody - change it. I have root access to my machine. I try with mokutil -c , but PC still asks for password, when boot. I try also change password by mokutil --password , but change do not been applied.

What to do?
Edit 1:
strace mokutil --clear-password gives:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/MokPW-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/MokPW-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
ioctl(4, FS_IOC_GETFLAGS, [FS_IMMUTABLE_FL]) = 0
ioctl(4, FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, [0])          = 0
write(4, "\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 176)
```

I do not known, what character with code at beginning of string means. I think it could be string size, but not sure. And why setting string size to 7, when there are only and of string characters?

Edit 2:

I follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226185/kernel-module-mokutil-failed-to-enroll-new-keys . And do:

```
mokutil --set-verbosity true #optional
mokutil --password #enter password when prompted
mokutil --import MOK.der #enter same password
```

Set password do one digit. After mok tells I reach maximum number of bad password, Verfication success console message appear and nothing - OS start normally.

Comment: Try `sudo mokutil --revoke-import` or `sudo mokutil --reset` or `sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key` to set a new key.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you could try to set a new key with command
`sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key`.

In case of a failure, this is sometimes caused by having a MOK
enroll/import operation that is still in progress.

To cancel it, use `sudo mokutil --revoke-import` or `sudo mokutil --reset`.